# call method from a function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I can not compile with c++11 . I can write in another form, but I want this code with the correction only on line ERROR, or I want a solution with non static check2 function .

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class If {
            public:
                struct Command {
                    string pattern;
                    bool (If::*check)(const string&, const string&);
                    function<bool(const string&, const string&)> check2;
                };
                If() {
                        Command command;
                        command.check = &If::check_true;
                        command.check2 = this->check2_true;
                        m_commands.push_back(command);
                }
                int modify() {
                    string result;
                    for (auto i = m_commands.begin(), end = m_commands.end(); i != end; ++i) {
                        if (((i)->*(Command::check))(i->pattern, result)) return EXIT_SUCCESS; // ERROR
                        if (this->*(i->check2)(i->pattern, result)) return EXIT_SUCCESS; // OK but i don't wont static function
                    }
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                bool check_true(const string& pattern, const string& value) { return true; }
                static bool check2_true(const string& pattern, const string& value) { return true; }
            private:
                vector<Command> m_commands;
        };
```

ERROR: 
     if (((i)->*(Command::check))(i->pattern, result)) return EXIT_SUCCESS;

no static:
     bool check2_true(const string& pattern, const string& value) { return true; }

Thank all

Comment: please include a [mcve] and the complete error message. btw why do you use a function pointer? There is only a single function that you can possibly assign to `Command::check`

Comment: "ERROR" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: ERROR is that don't compile

Comment: In real I have many function that depends on "If" constructor

Answer (score 2):

`check` is not a static member of `Command` - it's a member of `*i` - so you should use the normal member access syntax, `i->check`.
Also, the `If` instance you can call the member function on is `*this`.

```
(this->*(i->check))(i->pattern, result)
```

Note that the outer parentheses in `(this->*(i->check))` are required while the inner ones aren't, but I think the inner parentheses make it slightly more readable.

You can increase the readability further with a type alias, a function, and a range loop:

```
class If
{
public:
    using CommandFunction = bool (If::*)(const string&, const string&);
    // Alternative: typedef bool (If::*CommandFunction)(const string&, const string&);
    struct Command {
        string pattern;
        CommandFunction check;
    };
    If() {
        Command command;
        command.check = &If::check_true;
        m_commands.push_back(command);
    }
    bool call(CommandFunction f, const string& a, const string& b)
    {
        return (this->*f)(a, b);
    }
    int modify() {
        string result;
        for (const auto& i: m_commands) {
            if (call(i.check, i.pattern, result)) 
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    bool check_true(const string& pattern, const string& value) { return true; }
private:
    vector<Command> m_commands;
};
```

Comment: your solution don't compile on cpp.sh with c++11 or c++14

Comment: Great!!! That's works. My compiler don't recognize using .. but all right. It's possible to eliminate the call function  ?

Comment: @MarioRollino Yes you can eliminate the call - all it does is `(this->*(i->check))(i->pattern, result)` - but I personally find it difficult to decode member-pointer-dereferencing code.

Comment: @MarioRollino If your compiler doesn't support the `using` from "new" standards (C++11 is almost a decate old), use `typedef`. (See edit.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code (apart from the missing `#include`s and `std::`-prefixes)

First you are trying to use the class member `Command::check`, but there are (possibly) multiple `Command`-objects, each with their own `check`-member. You have to specify which `Command` object you want to access.

Since you are looping through a vector of `Command`-objects using the `i`-iterator, I assume you want to access the `check-member` of whatever `i` is referencing. Like this: `i->check`

Second: `check` is pointing to the method  `check_true`, which is a member of class `If`. That means when calling `check_true` you also have to specify which `If` object the method should act upon (the member `check` does not contain that information)

Typically that means when calling `check_true` directly you do it like this:

```
a.check_true(..) // `a` is of type `class If`
```

or
    b->check_true(..) // `b` is of type `class If *`

when doing it indirectly through a function pointer (in your case `i->check`) you do it like this:

```
a.*(i->check)(...) // `a` is of type `class If`
```

or

```
b->*(i->check)(...) // `b` is of type `class If *`
```

But you are calling it like this:

```
(i)->*....
```

and `i` is not a pointer to an `If` object, but a reference to a `Command` object.

Since you are doing all this inside `If::modify()`, I also assume `(i->check)(..)` should act upon the same `If`-object as `modify()` is currently acting upon. So the corrected function call should be:

```
this->*(i->check)(i->pattern, result)
```

Comment: your solution don't compile on cpp.sh with c++11 or c++14

Comment: (this->*(i->check))(i->patter, result) works. Thanks